# How can I specify custom chrome arguments when launching selenium chromedriver?

Tags: language-agnostic, selenium-chromedriver

In this specific case I want to use the chrome CLI switch `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` but it should work for any available chrome switch.

Any language is fine, I'd like this question to serve as documentation for how to do this in different languages.

Full disclosure: I intend to answer this for a few languages myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Ruby

```
Selenium::Webdriver.for(
  :chrome,
  switches: %w(
    --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
  )
)
```

#### Java

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

#### Python

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path/to/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```